# iOS: Location Update in Application Suspended State

Tags: ios, swift, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager

Is it possible to update location when application is in suspended/terminate state.

i want to update location every 500 meters when app is in suspended/terminate state.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When terminated the only real way to get updates is to use Region Monitoring but you will only get major updates so I doubt it will work for 500 meters.

From the documentation:

> If your app is terminated either by a user or by the system, the
>   system doesn't automatically restart your app when new location
>   updates arrive. A user must explicitly relaunch your app before the
>   delivery of location updates resumes. The only way to have your app
>   relaunched automatically is to use region monitoring or
>   significant-change location service. However, when a user disables the
>   Background App Refresh setting either globally or specifically for
>   your app, the system doesn't relaunch your app for any location
>   events, including significant change or region monitoring events.
>   Further, while Background App Refresh is off your app won't receive
>   significant change or region monitoring events even when it's in the
>   foreground.

There are good reasons for this.  Firstly people don't want apps that 'snoop' on them all the time and even if there is a good reason imagine having 10 apps doing this constantly.  It's going to start causing you performance and battery life issues.

**EDIT**
There appears to be some confusion by a lot of people over this issue so I will attempt to clear things up a bit.

Your app is NOT supposed to be continually tracking location while terminated (or suspended really).  You are just not allowed to do this both for privacy reasons and so that you don't drain the battery excessively.

While your app is in the foreground you can use location services via startUpdatingLocation to monitor the device location.  Assuming the app has been granted permission this will use all available hardware (GPS, WiFi, Cellular).

Now from the documentation itself:

> If you start this service and your app is suspended, the system stops
>   the delivery of events until your app starts running again (either in
>   the foreground or background). If your app is terminated, the delivery
>   of new location events stops altogether. Therefore, if your app needs
>   to receive location events while in the background, it must include
>   the UIBackgroundModes key (with the location value) in its Info.plist
>   file.

So once suspended and terminated your options are really to monitor regions and to monitor for significant location changes.  Neither of these are particularly accurate or frequent.  One reason for this is that they only use low power methods to get the position (WiFi and Cellular) they don't use the GPS.

So no accurate and/or frequent location tracking while an app is suspended or terminated.  This just has to be accepted and you need to design your apps accordingly.

Comment: i want to refresh location when location service unable and by the way why are you given negative vote?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background?language=objc

Comment: @user2105008 while the downvote was perhaps a bit harsh there are a lot of questions like this that talk about wanting to track locations when in the background or suspended.  You make no mention of why and so it's difficult to determine it there is a good reason for it or if you are just trying to track the user.  I could have just given the down vote and tried to move on but I did at least try to answer the question.  In this case as you have researched and appear to be genuine (and I may have been a bit harsh) I have removed it.  Keep on working on it.

Comment: i have ask question not only for me, there are so many people are struggle with user tracking. Location update is working when app is in terminate/suspended state but not accurate. there are 3 ways like start monitoring, startSignificateLocationUpdate and StartUpdatingLocation.

Comment: That is many people are trying to do something you are not supposed to do.  You are not supposed to be accurately tracking location when your app has been terminated (or suspended really).  Rather than explain in this comment I will update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

After returning a current location fix, the receiver generates update events only when a significant change in the user’s location is detected. It does not rely on the value in the distanceFilter property to generate events

If you start this service and your app is subsequently terminated, the system automatically relaunches the app into the background if a new event arrives. In such a case, the options dictionary passed to the application(*:willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) and application(*:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) methods of your app delegate contains the key location to indicate that your app was launched because of a location event. Upon relaunch, you must still configure a location manager object and call this method to continue receiving location events. When you restart location services, the current event is delivered to your delegate immediately. In addition, the location property of your location manager object is populated with the most recent location object even before you start location services.

```
Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification. It should not expect notifications more frequently than once every five minutes. If the device is able to retrieve data from the network, the location manager is much more likely to deliver notifications in a timely manner.
```

Hope It helps

Comment: you can take value of location by this                                                                    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    //print(launchOptions![UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.location])
    return true
  }